# How to run TestNG with JBehave

Tags: java, junit, testng, jbehave, testng-eclipse

My Story file:

```
**Given** a calculator
**When** I add 2 and 9
**Then** the outcome should 11
```

My Java Class:

```
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.Given;
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.When;
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.Then;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test
public class debugPluginSteps {
private Calculator myCal;
@Given("a calculator")
public void setCal() {
    myCal=new Calculator();
    System.out.println("Created");
}


@When("I add $number1 and $number2")
public void AddCal(int x,int y) {
    myCal.addTwoNumber(x, y);
}

@Then("the outcome should $result")
public void testResult(int output) {
     Assert.assertEquals(output, myCal.getresult());
    //System.out.println("Result : " + output);
}
```

Another java class in which I have written another method to sum two integer values:

```
public class Calculator {
private int sum;

public Calculator() {
    this.sum = 0;
}

public void addTwoNumber(int x, int y) {
    sum = x + y;
}

public int getresult() {
    return this.sum;
}
```

I have also included TestNG, Jbehave and gherkins(jar) file in my build path.
I am not getting option to run as testNG.
Also, I have created testNG.xml file.
So my first question is how to interlink story file and feature file with testNG and second thing how to run it using testNG

Comment: Have you even bothered to read the [FAQ](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/faq.html)?

Comment: @user3707125
I have been through FAQ,
It is mentioned that we can use TestNG but no where it is given as to how I can use it.

Comment: And what about this piece of code: `class YourStory extends JUnitStory/Stories { 
    @org.testng.annotations.Test 
    public void run()` ?

Comment: Using @org. **testng** annotation?

Comment: can u provide more details on the above annotation
I'm not sure where should i include it